# Laravel / PHPUnit: Asserting sameness of two models

Tags: php, laravel, testing, types, phpunit

When integration testing (using a database) in Laravel. What is the best way to assert that two instances of the same Eloquent model are the same?

#### AssertEquals `$model $model`

Simply using `->assertEquals($modelOne, $modelTwo);` wont work as even if they **are** the same PHPUnit checks class properties such as `wasRecentlyCreated`  and sometimes model `id`s can be a string or an integer.

#### AssertEquals `$model->id $model->id`

The problem here is model one may be an instance of another model e.g:

`AssertEquals(Person::find(1)->id, Animal::find(1)->id);` returns true.

#### AssertEquals `$model->toArray() $model->toArray()`

The issue here is properties are not always cast as the same type, Im not 100% sure why but there are times a models properties will be an `int` and other times a number `string`

`AssertEquals($address->toArray(), $user->address->toArray())`

```
[ postcode => 2454 ]
[ postcode => "2454" ]
```

**How to assert in a simple, clean and repeatable manner two Eloquent models are the same database record?**

Comment: Do you only want to compare models that you got fresh from the database?

Comment: Could you add some context for what exactly you're trying to test? Are you testing whether something like `Model::create()` is persisting properly, or ...?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

One option would be to use PHPUnit's `assertTrue` method combined with the `is` method on the `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent` class.

```
$this->assertTrue($modelOne->is($modelTwo));
```

The `is` method will return true if the model you pass as an argument is not `null`, has the same primary key, same table and same connection.

With regards to testing the sameness of attributes, you should be safe just using PHPUnit's `assertEquals` on each model's attributes, which you can retrieve using `getAttributes`.

```
$model1 = new Model(['id' => 1, 'name' => 'test', 'enabled' => 0, 'number' => '1']);
$model2 = new Model(['id' => 1, 'name' => 'test', 'enabled' => false, 'number' => 1]);

$this->assertEquals($model1->getAttributes(), $model2->getAttributes());
```

In my tests, I have found that these assertions pass. The `assertEquals` method compares values loosely, in that values are compared as using `==` rather than the strict comparison (or identity) operator, `===`. Internally, it will sort both of the arrays provided, and loosely compare values with the same keys. If you have any extra attributes on one model but not the other, the assertion will fail as well.

Comment: Wow this is great, exactly what I expected. Although missing the "sameness" in the sense that properties could be different prior to saving the record.

Comment: Has anyone written some assertions such as `assertModelEquals(Model $expected, Model $actual)` and `assertModelSameness(Model $expected, Model $actual)`?

Comment: I think you should be safe using `assertEquals` on each model's attributes. Please see my updated answer.

Comment: Whats the difference between toArray and getAttributes?

Comment: `getAttributes` simply returns the internal array that represents the attributes of the model. `toArray` does a lot more in that it invokes mutators, includes relations, casts attributes (as defined by the `$casts` property), omits hidden (as defined by the `$hidden` property) among other things. `getAttributes` is much simpler, it doesn't do any extra processing, it just returns the underlying data that the model represents.

Comment: Note that if you want to be more strict, you can use `assertSame` instead of `assertEquals`, which is the same as using `===` instead of `==`. Each has its own uses.